# General questions on C programming

Tags: c

I am a python developer. I am studying the C programming language. I have covered most of the basics and slowly moving to advanced usage of C. I have the following questions.

1. In C, `#ifndef _obj_h` based on what we use the underscore. E.G. if my header file is `obj.h`, then will I use it as `_obj_h`. What if I have a header file named `my_test_header.h` ? Will I use it as `_my_test_header_h`? What is the naming convention here?
2. Does C99 allow just in time initialization like for e.g. `for( int i = 0  .... )`? My compiler throws error. But in many books it is defined as legal.
3. Kindly Share any good resource for advanced usage of C programming, which discusses the development strategies, language usage.

Comment: By the way, you could have at least stuck a "please" in front of the last question...

Comment: Third question is off-topic, but here goes: It might be useful to read a coding standards reference, such as MISRA-C or similar. (Costs money, can someone suggest a free alternative?) They contain a lot of "best practices" for writing safety-critical C code, and many of them are good practice in general as well.

Comment: Is MISRA any good?  I was working on a project using it the other day and it seems to be full of crazy stuff.  I've never read the spec itself, though, just this code that purported to adhere.

Comment: I'd say when reading something like that for instructional purposes (rather than a manager telling you to follow it to the letter), take everything with a pinch of salt and follow the rules that make sense to you. I'm not familiar with the entire standard myself, but there may be some crazy stuff in there, I dunno. Of course, strict adherence to a coding standard is no guarantee that the code won't be garbage anyway, so it may have been the programmers' fault and not the standard. :P

Comment: Sorry.. was in a hurry, am not demanding. i am just requesting.. Added "kindly" to the last point..

Comment: Please research these as separate questions.  Ideally find the answers to them yourselves, but post here if you can't.  Except (3), that is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: @CarlNorum I went over what the MISRA site shows of it once or twice. Lots of sensible stuff and some plain lunacy (no recursion, for example) to make it indigestible.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that's an example of a rule I'd ignore completely. "Don't use recursion, because recursion can lead to stack overflows!" Oh, okay. Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The primary and most important naming convention is that **don't use multiple consecutive instances of the same punctuation mark!!!!!!!!**

Apart from that usual annoyance: identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them. Also, preprocessor macros are generally to be written in `ALL_CAPS` in order them to be easily distinguished from normal identifiers, functions, etc. So write your include guards like this:

```
#ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H

/* ... */

#endif
```

> C99 does it allow just in time initialization like for e.g. for( int i = 0 .... )? My compiler throws error. But in many books it is defined as legal.

Then tell your compiler to use C99. Maybe try `-std=c99`, works for GCC and clang (but it should not be necessary for `clang`, it defaults to C99 mode).

> Share any good resource for advanced usage of C programming, which discusses about the development strategies, usage.

**No.**

[(But you may want to format and indent your code...)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle)

Comment: clang compiles in C99 mode by default.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes it does, perhaps OP is using GCC or some non-compliant bastard like MSVC.

Comment: OP's profile page says India - it's my experience that most beginners there are forced to use Turbo-C++.  Barf.

Comment: @CarlNorum Social engineering :P

Comment: I am using Gcc 4.3 ... in mac.. Thanks

Comment: @Bala Don't do that. Use `clang` if you are on OS X. And next time google the compiler error message, it should not be hard, should it.

Comment: What if i want to include a header file named "my_first_header.h", so will i write it as #ifndef MY_FIRST_HEADER_H". is this valid ??

Comment: @Bala I don't see in what that differs from your previous example, please clarify.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Thanks a lot. i will use clan here after.. I did use google, but lots of contradictions. Does Xcode, by default comes with clang ?

Comment: @Bala Yes, it does. AFAIK you have to install the "Xcode command line tools" (misleading name).

Comment: @H2CO3 - my way understanding is .. 1) write all in caps. 2)convert '.' to '_' . So if i have a file like my-test-header.h, i will write it as MY-TEST-HEADER_H. so all i am doing is converting the dot to underscore.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Great !! Thanks will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @Bala dashes are disallowed. You would use `MY_TEST_HEADER_H` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use the leading underscore at all - identifiers that start with an underscore are reserved for file-scope identifiers by the implementation.  People still do it a lot in their code, but they probably shouldn't.

   Standard reference **7.1.3 Reserved Identifiers**:

   > — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
2. Yes, that's allowed.  Your compiler is too old, or you're not passing it the right flags to compile in C99 or C11 mode.
3. Off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. In C "_" underscore is just used to make easy to distinguish each names and it needs to satisfy sm times the rules to be unique so v use underscore
   2.ya u can use this format for but complier shd be updated 
   3.google is best one